# array does not echo correc value

Tags: php, arrays

I just initialize an array `$exp_arr` with some values. The `print_r($exp_arr[0])` results the following values

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40
        [email] => shishir012010@gmail.com
        [company_name] => Yahoo
        [title] => Developer2
        [location] => Noida
        [description] => 
        [smonth] => January
        [syear] => 2012
        [emonth] => December
        [eyear] => 2015
        [status] => 0
    )

)
```

After that `echo $exp_arr[0]['location']` does not print anything.

I also tried `var_dump($exp_arr[0]['location'])` and it results in output of `NULL`.

I can't track the problem. I have put the echo statement just after the print_r statement just like that

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($exp_arr[0]);
echo $exp_arr[0]['location'];
var_dump($exp_arr[0]['location']);
```

Comment: try `echo $exp_arr[0][0]['location'];`

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the validity of @kamalpal's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain Karma Pals point, your array is already one deep in a 0 index, so if you do this:

```
print_r($exp_arr[0][0]['location'])
```

You will get your location out. You need to check if your array structure is correct based on that.

Your vardump of just $exp_arr will look like something this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [email] => shishir012010@gmail.com
            [company_name] => Yahoo
            [title] => Developer2
            [location] => Noida
            [description] => 
            [smonth] => January
            [syear] => 2012
            [emonth] => December
            [eyear] => 2015
            [status] => 0
        )

    )
)
```